# How to create a timer that counts down from 99% to 0% reducing by 1% every second

Tags: c, timer

I'm trying to create a timer to display in the top right hand corner of a game that counts from 99% down to 0% with 1% being dropped every second and the counter refreshing on the screen. ps (i'm new to coding so sorry if this is a dumb question)

I've tried using a simple countdown loop but it decreases all at once, and doesn't save the counter as a variable, which i need so i can print it at a specific point on the screen

```
void battery_life(){
     int w, h;
    get_screen_size(&w, &h);

    int y=99;
    while (y !=0)
    y--;
    draw_int (2*w/3+5,h-h+2,y);
    draw_char(2*w/3+7,h-h+2,'%');
}
```

I expect that when i run this counter it -1% every second but it just counts down all at once and displays 0%

Comment: Your `while` body has 1 single statement. Try adding a block `{ ... }` with the 3 statements. Of course that will still be too fast, but maybe you can see what happens with your debugger.

Comment: This is really too broad. You will need some manner of system-dependent timer. Then either poll it or execute something from a callback when the timer fires. Then update graphics accordingly. In a professional application this will be executed by different threads - you wouldn't have application logic in the thread handling graphic updates.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather broad question, but here are several general approaches, which all need to:

1. Separate the game logic from rendering, and
2. Using a state machine for updating game state, instead of pausing the execution.

Here are two different approaches:

1. **Game loop**

   Since you are designing a game, it's likely you will have a [game loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure) of some sort, i.e.:

   ```
   while (!ending)
   {
       process_input();
       update_state();
       draw();
   }
   ```

   And your `update_state` and `draw` functions should have different responsibilities, similar to:

   ```
   static int current_percentage = 100;
   void update_state(void)
   {
       // keep the time of last update
       static timestamp last_update_time = 0;

       // decrease 'current_percentage' when needed
       timestamp now = get_current_game_time();
       if (seconds_elapsed(now, last_update_time) >= 1)
       {
           last_update_time = now;
           current_percentage--;
       }
   }

   void draw(void)
   {
       // just handle the drawing
       draw_percentage(current_percentage);
   }
   ```
2. **Multiple threads**

   On the other hand, if you are using multiple threads, you would likely end up with a rather different approach:

   ```
   static atomic_int current_percentage = 100;
   void decrease_percentage(void)
   {
        atomic_fetch_sub(&current_percentage, 1);
   }

   void draw(void)
   {
       // just handle the drawing
       int percentage = atomic_load(&current_percentage);
       draw_percentage(percentage);
   }

   // no game loop - we will need to configure function callbacks
   // for different events
   void on_game_start(void)
   {
       // one thread should update the timer
       call_periodically(1000 /* period in ms */, decrease_percentage /* what to call */);

       // this should run at max possible fps
       call_when_idle(draw /* what to call when idle */);
   }
   ```

The latter approach is slightly shorter, although the main reason for this is because a lot of functionality is hidden inside the functions which configure the callbacks. The former one is simpler to reason about and doesn't have issues which arise with multithreaded code (deadlocks, race conditions - note the use of the `atomic_int` to ensure atomic updates), which is why a game loop is preferred if possible.

If your game needs to utilize multiple cores, then you will need to involve some sort of threading, which comes with its additional complexity. The implementation of the second approach would also depend on your platform, since timers are not a part of the C standard.

Finally, if you are using a game engine/framework (libgdx, Unity), you will likely have to implement the `update` and `draw` callbacks only, with the framework taking care of calling these functions when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing brackets from your while loop so it's not going to work for a start!

You really need to implement a timer so that you can actually tell when a second has passed as your code could vary in operation speed, and definitely will when you make any changes. 
How you do this is totally up to the system you are writing on and you haven't given enough information for us to help you. 
Most often hardware running C has hardware timers and specific registers you need to target.

Comment: Thank you, is there any chance you could give an example of a timer code or a link to one? (also i'm just using straight c in a bash shell

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53841/how-to-use-a-timer-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

- Your while does nothing. If you don't put your code inside brackets, it only executes the next line in a loop.
- You're not waiting for a second anywhere.
- You should probably rethink your approach - if you fix the above problems, when you call the function everything else in your program will freeze for 99 seconds except for the battery text changing.

Maybe a better approach would be to write a function that has a `static int y = 99`, and each time you call it draw the battery text and decrease `y` by 1 (static more or less means the value is remembered between calls).

Then, in your main game loop, you can check if a second has passed, and if so, execute that function.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using unity, You can simply use a coroutine to countdown percentage per seconds.

```
void countDown()
{
    int percent = 99;
    StartCoroutine(CountDownToZero(percent));
}


IEnumerator CountDownToZero(int percentage)
{
    WaitForSeconds wait1sec = new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    while(percentage > 0)
    {
        percentText.text = percentage.ToString()+"%";
        yield return wait1sec;
        percentage= percentage- 1;
    }
    percentText.text = "0%";
}
```

In case of other engines, they also provide scheduler to schedule the execution of functions.

Comment: The OP never mentions Unity and has tagged  "C", not "C#".